# How to make an MSI with Visual Studio 2012 and Installshield LE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, installshield

I've been given a Visual Studio solution someone else made. It has an installer project using Installshield LE. The installer builds fine but it makes an exe and I'm supposed to make an msi. I know the guy who wrote the project would generate msi files but I just don't see any options to do it. Is this doable with LE?

Comment: What happens when you run the .exe file?

Comment: The exe works just fine.

Comment: There are scenarios where an EXE is required but it does add the additional complication of cache management.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go to step 6 and drill down to the Single Image release type.  Set Compression on the build tab to yes and set setup launcher on the setup.exe tab to no.  Build this release.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for the help, guys.  These tips sorted my issue.

After so many 1990s-looking releases, its amazing that InstallShield finally went to the trouble to make their Visual Studio integration so friendly... yet hid this vital option away.

I'm adding a screenshot, to help other users.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've solved it by using the following

- By using SingleImage as the build type
- Under - Setup.exe tab (Build  | **Setup.exe** | Signing)
- Select Setup Launcher = No.

The build from InstallShield will come out as a .MSI file under

(\RELEASE_PROJECT\Express\SingleImage\DiskImages\DISK1)

Comment: For me, the .msi was not located under SingleImage/DiskImages/Disk1. I searched my computer and found it in a different location: Users/myusername/AppData/Local/DownloadedInstallations