# Include cab into msi with InstallShield

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, installshield

I am building an msi package using Visual Studio 2013 and InstallShield limited edition.

I need all of the content to be shipped in a single msi file. By enabling compression I've managed to build a cab and msi files. If shipped alone msi will complain about missing files.

I've found several solutions for archaic versions of InstallShield but none for my current setup. Help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an MSI with Visual Studio 2012 and Installshield LE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641806/how-to-make-an-msi-with-visual-studio-2012-and-installshield-le)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Completely different problem.

Comment: Nonsense, it's the exact same problem.  You need to make sure you are building the right release. (SingleImage)