# Outlook add-in doesn't work without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, outlook

I have developed Outlook 2010 addIn project and I have to setup this  to users computers. When there is Visual Studio installed in user's computer it is ok. But when there is not installed Visual Studio , then my AddIn doesn't work. I don't want to install FULL Visual Studio.  I thought to install "Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime" would help, but it didn't. What have I to do for this?.

Comment: This means that these computers are missing some component that comes with VS. Is .NET framework installed on these machines?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't very descriptive - do you get any error messages? If not, are you able to add any code to do "printf" style debugging (pop up a message box at various difference places and see which ones show up)?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic .NET framework is installed, but VS not. The problem is that the AddIn only works on machines that have VS installed. 
In my situation, the FormRegion is shown but the content is not shown. there must be some components, i.e gridview, buttons etc.

Comment: You can only have dependencies on items that your Add-In references. Is there anything in your project references that is "obviously" VS related? (You may want to edit your question to show all of your references, if you're unsure on some of them)

Comment: Try enabling FusLogVw to see if any assemblies aren't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had added Visual Basic component (LineShape) to my FormRegion. And my project is written in C#. So this was making some conflict. I removed that VB component , and it is solved.

Thanks you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create an InstallShield project for your Outlook Addin (from within Visual Studio) and accept its default options to include the necessary dependencies.   The end result is an .msi file with everything the users would need to run your Addin.

[Creating a InstallShield project from VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641806/how-to-make-an-msi-with-visual-studio-2012-and-installshield-le/32374161#32374161)

As the other comments have mentioned, *some dependency* is missing from your user's PCs.

You just need to work out what is missing (and no, it's not a full installation of Visual Studio !)

Comment: Thanks for reply. How to determine what is missing? I Publish my full project, so I think all references must be included. Isn't it?

Comment: Not really, no.  
Creating an InstallShield project will look at what other package/libraries need to be included.   The other thing to look at is your list of References in your VSTO project.  Generally, a VSTO Addin should just need .Net, VS Tools for Office, and whatever extra stuff you've included in your References.